# Load different Javascript functions in each page load on different devices

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage contains of 2 Javascript functions. Let's say eatApple() and eatOrange().

Both of them will randomly return a value of 1 or 2. Now I need to achieve the below:

**1st page load on Computer A**

- eatApple() is fired
- it returns a value of "1", it means "It is a good function! Keep using it"

**2nd page load on Computer B**

- eatApple() is fired again
- it returns a value of "2", it means "this function is BAD, please use another one"

**3rd page load on Computer C**

- eatOrange() is fired
- it returns a value of "2", it means "this function is BAD, please use another one"

**4rd page load on Computer D**

- eatApple() is fired

.......the switching of eatApple() and eatOrange() continues in this manner

I tried to use a variable to store the value returned by the function. But it doesn't work as the variable will be reset on every new page load. I guess there should be a method to store the variable in somewhere externally, and call it later?

Please note that eatApple() and eatOrange() should never fire together in the same page load. Only 1 function should be fired.

Thanks.

**Updated on 24 Jul to describe the case clearer. Different page load is happened on different devices instead of the same device**

Comment: Another case for `window.localStorage()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Different devices? You're going to need a server of some sort

Comment: Hi David, yes I am also thinking of something like a server, but I am not sure what kind of programming language should I use (as I am only familiar with JS and HTML)